# RouterOS hairpin nat produces input does not match any value of interface

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, nat, mikrotik-routeros

I have RouterOS v6.39.2 (stable)

- external IP: 134.249.116.246
- router IP: 192.168.88.1
- internal server IP: 192.168.88.245

I setup a regular port forwarding via

```
  ip firewall nat add chain=dstnat dst-address=134.249.116.246 protocol=tcp dst-port=8080 action=dst-nat to-addresses=192.168.88.245 to-ports=8080
```

Attempt to setup a hairpin NAT

```
 ip firewall nat add chain=srcnat src-address=192.168.88.0/24 dst-address=192.168.88.245 protocol=tcp dst-port=8080 out-interface=LAN action=masquerade
```

failed due to:

```
input does not match any value of interface
```

I can't understand what is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be the "out-interface=LAN" section. Had a similar issue and changed it to the specific interface "out-interface=eth5" and the rule was added.

However, even after saving, the hairpin NAT isn't working for me.
Try and let us know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `out-interface-list=LAN` instead of `out-interface=LAN`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1109886)

Comment: To be honest, this is the most accurate answer that can be provided, of course, I can add a note that op used the wrong syntax. But still this is a really clear solution for the issue.